# Auto rollout kubernes deployment if the deployment fails in azuredevops

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kubernetes, azure-devops

We have a release pipeline in AzureDevops to deploy the microservice to AKS and send the log of the microservice once its deployed.
We are using below command to deploy the deployment with the template kubectl and command as "-f /home/admin/builds/$(build.buildnumber)/Myservice_Deployment.yml --record"

Here we noticed that the task is not waiting for the existing pod to terminate and crate the new pod, but its continuing and just finishing the job.

Our expected scenario

1) Deploy the microservice using kubectl apply -f /home/admin/builds/$(build.buildnumber)/Myservice_Deployment.yml --record

2) wait for the existing pod to terminate and ensure that the new pod is in running status.

3) once the new pod is running status collect the log of the pod by kubectl log command and sent to the team

4) if the pod is not is not in running state, roll back to previous stable state.

I tried with different shell scripts to achieve this in azuredevops, but didnt succeeded

Ex:

```
ATTEMPTS=0
ROLLOUT_STATUS_CMD="kubectl --kubeconfig /home/admin/kubernetes/Dev-kubeconfig rollout status deployment/My-service"
until $ROLLOUT_STATUS_CMD || [ $ATTEMPTS -eq 60 ]; do
  $ROLLOUT_STATUS_CMD
  ATTEMPTS=$((attempts + 1))
  sleep 10
done
```

Also need to get the log of the microservice using the kubectl log command and the file should be in the format with Date and need to be shared over mail..

Comment: how did this case go, any update?

Comment: Looking for a solution from script end and not from the kubernetes side

Answer (score 1):

you have several questions mixed up in a single question, but you'd need to configure your deployment with liveness probe for your desired behaviour to happen

Reading: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command

Comment: I guess it won't help here for my scenario. We are looking for a way to track the current deployment only whether the pod is created or not. But your solution is stating something about monitoring a particular. Both are different scenarioa

Comment: no, this will ensure new pod is running and only then delete the old pod. exactly what you are looking for

Comment: but looking for a solution in pipeline task side to check the status of deployment and rollout to previous stage  if the new deployment failed

Comment: I dont understand, if you do `kubectl apply` and deployment doesnt progress because of the liveness probe - you dont need to rollback, becaseu nothing was deployed

Comment: sorry if i confused you here. In my case the "kubectl apply" is one task in my pipeline and once it initiated , the pipeline is going further to execute the next task (while my old pod status is terminating only) . my next task to get the logs and since the new pod is not yet created , its just giving error. and even if the deployment failed also, we are not notified to rollout .. So looking for a automated way or script to wait till the new pod created and execute the next step for log if the deployment was succesful . else if the deployment faled- rollout to previous stage.

Comment: thats what liveness probe will do for you, but I'd think you need to use `apply` but `image set`